# Masking using Blending Function does not work on Android

Tags: android, function, libgdx, masking, blending

The code is made according to the example from the official LibGDX WIKI:

https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/masking#4-masking-using-blending-function-shapes-or-textures

**Works** on **DESKTOP**

**Does not work** on **Android**

Displaying a red square without applying alpha:

[image]

---

```
class LibGDXGame : Game() {

    private val batch by lazy { SpriteBatch() }

    private val mask by lazy { Texture("mask.png") }
    private val sprite by lazy { Texture("sprite.png") }

    private val maskSprite by lazy { Sprite(mask) }
    private val spriteSprite by lazy { Sprite(sprite).apply { color = Color.RED } }

    private val background by lazy { Texture("sprites/background/1.png") }


    override fun create() {}



    override fun render() {
        ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK)

        batch.begin()

        batch.draw(background, 0f, 0f, 1400f, 700f)
        batch.flush()

        drawMasks()
        drawMasked()
        drawOriginals()

        batch.end()
    }



    private fun drawMasks() {
        Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, true)

        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO)
        maskSprite.draw(batch)
        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA)
        spriteSprite.draw(batch)
        batch.flush()
    }

    private fun drawMasked() {
        Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true)

        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA)
        spriteSprite.draw(batch)
        batch.flush()
    }

    private fun drawOriginals() {
        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        batch.draw(maskSprite, 0f, 256f)
        batch.draw(spriteSprite, 256f, 256f)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PROBLEM:

### a = 0

```
package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android;

public class AndroidApplicationConfiguration {
    /** number of bits per color channel **/
    public int r = 8, g = 8, b = 8, a = 0;
}
```

---

### SOLUTION:

### a = 8

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration().apply {
       a = 8
}
```

---

[image]